# unmuting in C# using sendmessage commands

Tags: c#, audio, sendmessage

I know in c# it is possible to mute using appcommands such as

```
 APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
```

is there an unmute equivalent.  I know how to unmute and mute using the nuget package.  but when I the nuget package to does show on my audio bar on my laptop unlike the using the sendmessage function using APPCOMMAND's
.

Comment: send VOLUME_MUTE again? send VOLUME_UP? the p/invoke layer is shown here, if you don't want to use a lib: https://inneka.com/programming/c/how-to-programmatically-set-the-system-volume/

Comment: thank you Marc,  that worked.  another question I am using a slider to adjust the volume as well and in coding I use the nuget package.  how to get it to view on the audio display on my lcd screen like the sendmessage does .